# UTFT_SdRaw not loading image properly

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to load multiple images with the UTFT_SDRaw library. I had some .raw files from the internet and they worked nicely. Now I made an image in png and converted it to Raw with a program called:
"Fiji ImageJ". After converting I moved it to my 4gb 32Fat sdcard. Changed the code a bit and the old images still loaded but my image is like a rainbow dotted square. I assume the file type isn't right although it's .raw. I can't find any specifications on the working images or what so ever and can't find anything on google.

Does someone have a program that can be used to convert my pngs to raw properly?
Or is there something else i did wrong?